# In Angular ui-router child template not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

I have registered a state `test` with a child `.child1` , here parent (`test`) working fine . when i navigate to state `test.child1` URL gets changed to `#/test/child1` but the view remains same , child template not working

```
angular.module('uiRouterSample.contacts', [
  'ui.router'
])

.config(
  [          '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
    function ($stateProvider,   $urlRouterProvider) {
      $stateProvider
      .state('test',{
            url:'/test',            
            template:'<a ui-sref="test">Parent</a> -> <a ui-sref=".child1">child1</a>',
            controller: ['$scope', '$state', 'contacts', 'utils',
              function (  $scope,   $state,   contacts,   utils) {
              }]
        }).state('test.child1',{
            url:'/child1',            
            template:'Child template working fine'
        })
    }
  ]
)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need a `ui-view` directive in the template of the parent state (the test state):

```
  template:'<div ui-view/> <a ui-sref="test">Parent</a>  <a ui-sref=".child1">child1</a></div>',
```

Basically whenever you have a state in ui-router which will have child states, the immediate parent pf that child state must also have a `ui-view` directive in its template.

Comment: @Vimal I don't see a ui-view in the test state's template from the code you posted.

Answer (score 3):

Posting this as answer as I do not have enough reps to comment. As mentioned by Mohammad, you need a `ui-view` inside the template of the parent state. The `ui-view` in your Index html only allows you to render the parent state(`test` state), but in order for .child1 state to be rendered, it needs another `ui-view` inside its parent state, which in this case is the `test` state.

Thus, configure your `test` state's template to contain a `ui-view`:

```
angular.module('uiRouterSample.contacts', ['ui.router'])
.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
   function ($stateProvider,   $urlRouterProvider) {
     $stateProvider
       .state('test',{
         url:'/test',            
         template:'<div ui-view/> <a ui-sref="test">Parent</a> -> <a ui-sref=".child1">child1</a></div>',
         controller: ['$scope', '$state', 'contacts', 'utils',
           function (  $scope,   $state,   contacts,   utils) {
           }]})
    .state('test.child1',{
        url:'/child1',            
        template:'Child template working fine'
    })
   }]
```